# PHP Randomly select 3 things (%20, %20, %60) of the time?

Tags: php

how can I do something % of the time? for 3 different options? I can't figure out how to do it 3 way for example:

```
if 20% {
   code 20% of the time
} elseif 20% {
  code #2 20% of the time
} else %60 {
    code # 3 60% of the time
}
```

I know this works for one option or two, but how about 3?

```
$rand = mt_rand(1, 100); 
if ($rand > $successrate) // Success rate is your integer; 87 for 87% for example 
{ 
    // This is a failure. 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a random between 0 and 99 (because you're dealing with percentage), you can do this:

```php
$rand = mt_rand(0, 99);
if ($rand < 20) {
    //Do this 20% of the time
} elseif ($rand < 40) {
    //Do this 20% of the time
} else {
    //Do this 60% of the time
}
```

Or, if you prefer dealing with non-zero values

```php
$rand = mt_rand(1, 100);
if ($rand <= 20) {
    //Do this 20% of the time
} elseif ($rand <= 40) {
    //Do this 20% of the time
} else {
    //Do this 60% of the time
}
```

Note you can't use strict operators (or use < 21 / < 41) because, in this case, you'll have 19%, 19% and 62%

Comment: This would technically be 19.8% 19.8% and 60.4% .. then using 0 to 10 would be 18% 18% and 64% ....

Comment: @niconoe it's perfect I'm glad it's so easy thank you!

Comment: @Cole9350 This is interesting it should be `mt_rand(1, 100)`?

Comment: You're both right, the mt_rand should go to 99 and not 100, because from 0 to 100, there are 101 int values. Or if you prefer use mt_rand(1, 100), don't use strict operators. I'm editing my answer

Comment: @zumba yes, `mt_rand(1,100)` would give you 100 numbers instead of 101.. but you would also have to change less than to less than or equals

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following test:

```
if ($rand > 40) {
  // 41-100
} else if ($rand > 20) {
  // 21-40
} else {
  // 0-20
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works exactly the same

```
$rand = mt_rand(1, 100);
if ($rand >= 1 && $rand <= 20)
    // 20%
else if ($rand >= 21 && $rand <= 40)
    // 20%
else if ($rand >= 41 && $rand <= 100)
    // 60%
```

Comment: No brackets and multiple useless combinations in your conditions. But I'll not downvote your answer since it does the job too.

Comment: @niconoe: My code should be considered pseudo code - should have marked as such, sry. That's why there are no brackets. Also I wrote the interval boundaries explicitly in detail so it's clear how it works.